# find the percent of the time a number is greater or less than the values in a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = 
2018-06-15    0.096377
2018-06-18    0.095913
2018-06-19    0.073047
2018-06-20    0.065600
2018-06-21    0.063776
...
```

How do I query `df` what % of the time the df contents is greater/less than a particular #?

So if my entire `DataFrame` was like above, and I asked, what % of `df` > .07, it would return .50 (50%) since 3 of the numbers are > .07, and three are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I uderstood correctly, you can try the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2018-06-15',0.096377],
                        ['2018-06-18',0.095913],
                        ['2018-06-19',0.073047],
                        ['2018-06-20',0.065600],
                        ['2018-06-21',0.063776]], columns=['c1', 'c2'])
(df['c2'] > 0.07).sum()/df['c2'].count()
```

First I am defining the `DataFrame`. Then I am comparing with the value, in this case `0.7`, and calculating the sum of the true values in the column `c2`. By dividing the result by the `length/count` of the column you will get the desired output.
the output would be `0.6`